# Change network adapter properties without admin rights

Tags: networking, drivers, ethernet, administrator

The application developed by our sw team grabs images from an ethernet sensor/camera, adopting a sensor manufacturer SDK which in turn adopts GIGE vision protocol. It is a windows 10 desktop application. The workstation running the application needs a dedicated ethernet adapter, directly connected to the sensor by means of a direct cat5e or cat6 cable. The sensor manufacturer provides also its proprietary "filter driver" that need to be installed on the ethernet adapter.

Now we have to handle the case when the user can dinamically swtich to another model of sensor/camera from a different manufacturer, plugging it to the same ethernet card. Our  application, in order to grab images from the other sensor, need to dynamically disable the manufacturer 1 filter driver and enable the manufacturer 2 filter driver: the 2 filter drivers are not compatible with each other: when they are both enabled, it is not possible to grab images from any of the 2 sensors. In general: we need our application to dinamycally enable / disable properties of the ethernet adapter.
We succesfully obatined this behaviour programmatically. But now the request is to perform this without admin user right. Do you know if this can be accomplished? I didn't find any policy to allow standard user to change network adapter properties.
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

A standard user cannot do such actions on the network adapter.

If adding the user into the Administrators group is not possible,
it would perhaps be enough to just add him into the
Network Configuration Operators group.

Members of this group can make changes to TCP/IP settings,
and they can renew and release TCP/IP addresses.

---

If the problem is running an elevated program by a standard user,
there exist solutions that can be set up by an administrator
for that user.

One solution is to use a third-party product such as
[RunAsSpc](http://www.robotronic.de/runasspcEn.html)
to execute an elevated program while keeping secret the
administrator password itself.
The password is encrypted and is not visible to the user.
For more details see the article
[Pass the password to Runas with RunAsSpc](http://www.robotronic.de/guidance.html).

Other similar products are (without recommendation) :

- [AdvancedRun](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/advanced_run.html) (freeware)
- [Make Me Admin](https://github.com/pseymour/MakeMeAdmin/wiki/) (freeware)
- [RunAsTool](https://www.sordum.org/8727/runastool-v1-4/) (freeware)
- [Runasrob](https://runasrob.com/) (commercial)
  The free version has an annoying popup window which appears randomly.

Comment: thank you, if the user is added to Network Configuration Operators it is possible to change IP settings and enable / disabile the NIC, but it is not possible to change the other properties like enabling / disabling filter drivers.

Comment: In that case you need to run your program in elevated mode while keeping secret the administrator password. See the addition to my answer.